# Why doesn't Numpy allow chaining of conditional indexing?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to index one array based on the contents of another like so:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,100,10)
b = np.linspace(0,100,10)

print a[b<75]
```

This works fine, but what I really want to do is index based on two conditions, like this:

```
print a[25<b<75]
```

But this yields the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `[(25 > b) & (b > 75)]` The AND-operator doesn't work either?

Comment: Its closer but still not what I was looking for: it seems to produce just an array of Falses.

Comment: b larger than 75 and less than 25 will never be true..

Comment: Sorry, sorry. I got the inequalities the wrong way round in my example. Fixed now.

Comment: The solution from Allendar works now, but I would like to know why a[25<b<75] does not since it works fine in a pure python if statement, and why 'and' doesn't work instead of the ampersand.

Comment: It's simply a limitation of how numpy broadcasting works. use |\& instead of or\and. and you can't chain them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Python docs:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
>   to x < y and y <= z

But Numpy arrays do not fit the pattern `x < y and y <= z`, because it means `[a bool ndarray] and [a bool ndarray]`, and this requires that on both sides of the `and` the numpy ndarrays would have a bool value for the entire array (e.g., `b==True`), which is not defined.

Therefore, you have to use the binary bitwise operations on arrays for an element-wise "and": `(b > 25) & (b < 75)`.